# How to change tablecell selected color?

Tags: uitableview

I set the selected color of the cell, but why is it still the default gray when I click it for the first time? The second click will become the color I defined.

I tried to give the cell a background color, but it doesn't take effect on the first click.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            let backgroundView = UIView()
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView

   }       

}
```

I want the color I defined when I click it for the first time.

Comment: Can you write your cellForRowAt method ?

Answer (score 0):

You must change *selectedBackgroundView* before calling *didSelectRowAt* method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            let backgroundView = UIView()
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I did this, and my original cell is now white.

Comment: You are using custom tableview cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassed UITableViewCell, you can override setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) method in your custom tableview cell class

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```